Azure pipelines is failing with KuduStackTraceURL error
I'm trying to deploy fucntion app code via Azure DevOps release pipeline using Azure Function deploy task. A private endpoint is attcahed on this function app. I'm trying to deploy code via self-hosted agent[Linux Redhat VM]. Both private endpoint and linux vm are on same subnet. No NSG/Route table is applied on Subnet/NIC of VM. I'm getting below error
 ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
 ##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: KuduStackTraceURL
 ##[error]KuduStackTraceURL https://$<FuncionAppName>:***@<FuncionAppName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
 ##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Ip Forbidden (CODE: 403)


Is this even related to any networking or something else? I'm not using any slots as well.
Image Func App N/w section
I want the code to be deployed successfully without any errors.

If you deploy your app from that agent VM using other tools like Azure CLI az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n <app_name> --src <zip_file_path> would the 403 error be reproduced? Can you please share some screenshots showing how you setup PE for scm site? Please don't forget to remove any sensitive or private information such as token, password, certificate, IP etc. since the community is visible to public. If possibile, would you consider the workaround to deploy to slot and then swap the slots? The deployment to staging slot is via public network not via PE.

Hi Alvin, I don't have access to those agent machines(I'm trying to get access with my team) to install Azure CLI as of now AzCLI is not installed on them, but deploying on slot and swapping them is working fine. Thanks

Yes, deployment to slot is not restricted by PE. The issue is more likely to be caused by the network connections between your VM and the PE rather than Azure Pipelines. By the way, was your PE set for the SCM site for deployment or simply for main site? I didn't see it from the screenshot you shared. Sorry I am not so familiar with App Services as Azure DevOps. The information may probably help you narrow down the issue and isolate the root cause.
